# how expensive is a database wide query on MongoDB?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, heroku

I have a collection that contains user objects, each with a unique ID and some other stuff. This collection could have millions of entries. My question is how expensive would a query be that takes a list of say 300 UIDS, and then checks which of those exist in the collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two parts to this question #1: the query, #2: the performance.

**1: The query**

This can easily be done using the [`$in` clause](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in).

**2: The performance**

The thing about the `$in` clause is that there is only one logical way to do this from the DB perspective. It's basically going to do one index search for each item you have.

Now if you follow standard protocol and keep all of your index in RAM, then this query is probably going to come in under a second a so. I have some beefy servers with 100s of millions and such a search for 100 "UIDS" comes back in about 500ms.

YMMV. You may get better performance by chunking it out and running multiple simulataneous queries just to ensure that you're getting multiple threads going on the server.

Comment: So suppose I have a collection of millions of documents with a key "userid" and I have a set of "somepeople" for which I want to know whether they are in the collection (a bit like a union, in set theory, between userid and somepeople), the correct query would be: db.collection.find({"userid":{$in : somepeople}})? You mentioned keeping the index in RAM, how? And speaking of the index, am I correct in thinking I need to call db.collection.ensureIndex({userid:1}) every time before I make the $in call? Is that necessary even if userid is the primary key (I lied above, "userid" is actually "_id")

Comment: Lots of questions. First, `_id` is probably the correct user here. `_id` automatically has an index, so you have that covered, you won't need to call `ensureIndex` every time. "Keeping the index in RAM": take a look at the size of your indexes (`db.users.stats()`). That size should be less than the amount of RAM you have. MongoDB will do its best to keep indexes in RAM and maintain speed. But if your index is 4GB and you only have 2GB of RAM, then this whole thing will be slow.